# How to reserve space for iframe content without playing it

Tags: html, css, iframe, dynamic

I am creating a web page which is a showcase for various kinds of content. Some of the content comes with a HTML page which plays the content (Flash, WebGL) and I am trying to use iframes to load them on the web page. I could maybe add the content straight on my page since I have the actual content, but the editors generate readily usable HTML which works great. Therefore, I wouldn't want to start dissecting what are the important parts to add on my page to get all different types of content to play properly.

Still, all this works fine. The problem is, I don't want the content to play right away and I would like it to reserve the space it needs (i.e. the iframe should match the size of the content to be loaded). I know how to do each of these separately but not together. The idea is that there would be a button which plays the content and the content would start to play in its space without resizing the page.

I see two ways of achieve this, neither of which I know how to do.

1. Don't load the content before the play button is pressed but read the size of the content somehow.
2. Load the content and prevent it from activating/playing before the play button is pressed.

Closest to the desired effect I got by using `visibility: hidden` styling which did reserve the space and on top of that hide the iframe content (doesn't matter to me if its hidden or not) but the content started playing. Another way might be to read width and height values from the HTML file, but this information might be in a separate CSS file or there might several width and height values in the files. It would be a mess if I need to start creating exceptions for all sorts of content I load into iframes.

Is there an easy way to achieve either of these approaches? Or is there an alternative approach?

Answer (score 0):

You could load up the page with the iframes in the correct positions you need them, and set a blank page in the src attribute.

Then when they scroll into view, load the correct src attribute.

This can be achieved by using some `javascript` like this (using jQuery for ease, but not needed).

This is a rough example, and would need some refactoring:
https://jsfiddle.net/pLwL0843/2/

Comment: I think I was a little unclear with my initial post. I want the iframe to match the size of its content. This I've done with javascript by updating iframe size after loading the content. Part of my problem is that I don't know how to get the correct size without loading the content src.